# What are all these 0 kB .gifs from Google?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a web application using the Google Maps API (specifically through Angular's `ng-map` directive) and have noticed some strange behaviour when inspecting the [i]Network[/i] tab whilst debugging. Google appears to be requesting a series of .gifs from `csi.gstatic.com` along with a lot of http options. Here's an example of a full link:

> https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&v3v=29.14a&action=apiboot2&libraries=geometry%2Csearch&e=google-maps-embed,10_1_0,10_2_0&rt=main.8

All these requests return a `204`, though the type claims to be a .gif (as expected, can't view or open them.) Typically it will make 10 requests as the page loads (though sometimes less, somehow) and won't make anymore, even if there is additional map interaction.

What are these requests? Is there any way I can disable them?

Comment: Its a simple way to make a request with some associated data hit their servers and return something inconsequential.

Comment: @AlexK. I see - do you know specifically what they're doing? Or if there's an alternative way for Google to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the URL parameters: main, firstmap, firsttile, tilesloaded, as well as information like viewport and hidpi. Based on the names I would assume it's doing some sort of logging, sort of like Google Analytics.